# python def, print returned value

Tags: python, return, function

I am trying to get filenames that are written line by line in a text file. I have tried using the following code to return a name for each line in a variable called filenames. When I try to print the filenames variable to assure it has been properly retrieved, an error occurs stating the (filenames) is not defined. I also made a test variable to check if it is just not reading the lines correctly but the same error occurs. Any ideas?

```
def read(textFile):
    filenames = []
    test = "test"
    with open ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\multiUploadTest\\var.txt", "r+") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            filenames.append(line)
            print test
            print (filenames)
    return (filenames, test)

print (test)
print (filenames)
```

Comment: `test` and `filenames` are variables that are only available in your method scope because they are declared there

Comment: okay, so if I declared them as globals before the method they would work? I'm still a bit confused because I also tried printing them before the end of the method, there were no errors, but they weren't printed.

Comment: Yes but @jonrsharpe his way is a better solution

Comment: @hoos93 you could use `global`, then you wouldn't even need to `return`, but keeping the explicit arguments and outputs is a much better idea; it makes the code easier to develop and test, and means you can easily reuse the function elsewhere.

Comment: Is this your complete code? Because if so you haven't actually called `read` anywhere which would explain why the `print` inside the function didn't print anything. Also the `textFile` argument to `read` is never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` and `filenames` are only available inside your function. so you need to either call the function and assign the values to variable outside the function and then use them, or you could declare them as global in which case you don't need to return them.

So, you could either do this:

```
def read(textFile):
    filenames = []
    test = "test"
    with open ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\multiUploadTest\\var.txt", "r+") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            filenames.append(line)
            print test
            print (filenames)
    return (filenames, test)

filenames, test = read(your_filename)
print filenames, test
```

or you could the following:

```
def read(textFile):
    global filenames, test
    filenames = []
    test = "test"
    with open ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.new\\multiUploadTest\\var.txt", "r+") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            filenames.append(line)
            print test
            print (filenames)

read(your_filename)
print filenames, test
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, if I declare them as global, then they are accessible outside the function and I don't need to return them right?

Comment: but I tried this out and did not get any error. Here is the link to what I tried. http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user30_72u7vaH7L1_0.py

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you'd defined them inside the function - ignore me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to *do something* with the values you `return`, e.g.:

```
test, filenames = read("testing.txt")
print(test)
print(filenames)
```

Names in Python are just references to objects; returning `test` and `filenames` passes the *objects those names reference* back to the calling function, but *doesn't* mean that the *same names* will automatically be available. In fact, you can name them something completely different in the calling function and everything will still work:

```
foo, bar = read("testing.txt")
print(foo)
print(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error "C:\xampp\htdocs\test.new\multiUploadTest\var.txt", "r+" - because of the double \ - so the file can not be read.

This error has nothing to do with the code it has to do with file location, do a test, copy the file in the same folder as the code and then point the with open() to that folder, or just drop the \ and use a single \